# Hiding another html component with Select2 + Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to hide a div (id #pagos) when a select input (id #buy_sell) option has been chosen (using select2).

Doing it with JQuery and a standard select box is pretty easy, but I'm a bit new to using select2 and everything has gotten complicated.

So far, I have not been able to find a script that works, that's why I come to you.
This is the code I have so far. I would be very grateful for any corrections to make it work.

```
<script>
$("#buy_sell").change(function() {
  if ($("#buy_sell").select2("val") == "241|Vendo") {
    $('#pagos').show();
  } else {
    $('#pagos').hide();
  }
});
$("#buy_sell").trigger("change");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<div>
  <select id="buy_sell">
    <option value="1">First option</option>
    <option value="2">Last option</option>
  </select>
  <div id="pagos">Will be hidden if "2" is selected</div>
</div>

<script>
  $('document').ready(function() {
    $('select').select2();
    
    $('#buy_sell').on('change', function (e) {
      if (e.target.value === '2') {
        $('#pagos').hide();
      } else {
        $('#pagos').show();
      }
    })
  })
  
</script>
```